# Function undefined/null even with eval()

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, eval, hta

I need help and I do not understand what's going on.
I have a script get the list of files in a folder, and eval all the js files.
I inject some html, but when I use the html, it calls my function but it says a function (previously evaluated) isn't defined??

Edit: { Written in html, javascript, css, and vbs. In an HTA. }

I tried shifting the snippets around, but it still gives me the error. (and I cannot just copy and paste to the main file, its meant to be a plugin)

Code: (some not all)

```
var inject='<div id="console">\
<br><div id="consoletitle" class="dynDiv_moveParentDiv dynDiv_bodyLimit"><center>Console</center></div>\
<a id="consolekey"></a><a id="consolea"></a>\
<input type="text" id="consoleba" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){ss(event);}">\
</div>';
plugins.innerHTML+=inject;
```

this part works just fine, and the html is injected

```
function ss(event){
 var key=event.keycode;
 alert(key);
}
```

but it says this code isn't eval'd (or isn't defined)

and both snippets are in the same file that is eval'd.

Error:

```
Line: 1
Char: 23
Error: The value of the property 'ss' is null or undefined, not a function object
Code: 0
URL:
```

Here is the code that loads and evals each file:

```
var fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

This works fine.

```
function loadPlugins(){
    var fs=new Enumerator(fso.GetFolder("./plugins/").Files);
    for(;!fs.atEnd();fs.moveNext()){
        var file=fso.OpenTextFile(fs.item(),1);
        eval(file.readAll());
        file.close();
    }
}
```

Seems to be working too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is evaluated in the scope of the `loadPlugins` function, so the functions defined in the evaluated code only exist in that scope.

You can write the function as a function expression and assign it to a global variable to make it exist in the global scope:

```
ss = function(event){
 var key=event.keycode;
 alert(key);
};
```

Note: The `ss` variable is implicitly created in the global scope. If you use `var ss` it will be a local variable that only exists inside the function scope.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it works now. Can't believe I never thought of doing it like that. Good to know for future plugins.

Comment: I guess doing `var eee = eval; eee(code_to_be_evaled);` should cause the code to be evaluated in global scope.

Comment: @Prusse: Yes, getting the value of the `eval` function seems to change its behaviour. Ironically you can get the same using `eval('eval')(code_to_be_evaluated)`. :) I don't know how well supported it is to get the value of a built in function, though.

Comment: From [Annex E (informative) Additions and Changes in the 5th Edition that Introduce Incompatibilities with the 3rd Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-E) "10.4.2: In Edition 5, indirect calls to the eval function use the global environment as both the variable environment and lexical environment for the eval code. In Edition 3, the variable and lexical environments of the caller of an indirect eval was used as the environments for the eval code." I guess caution must be used here.

Comment: I will suggest to do `window.ss = function(){...}` to avoid the assignment from accessing a variable with the same name bound to the local scope.